# Can I ask questions like "How to do X in application Y"?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example I want to ask the following question:

> How to move items up and down in a Winamp playlist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. This is one of the topics we actually define specifically as on-topic on our [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - **Using a particular app on your Android device**
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android
>     device
>
> then this is the right place to ask.

Comment: I would, however, say that questions should show some research effort. If googling your question gives an answer on the vendor's website as the first result, the question is still on-topic, but you can expect it to be downvoted.

Comment: Also note that questions specific to some "service", but not directly Android-related, might be seen different ("general service-specific questions", which quite often pop up e.g. for Whatsapp). Let me put eldarerathis' emphasizing into that light: "Using a particular app ***on your Android device***", not "using a particular service in general" ;)